# Can't grab comment text using Selenium, python requests, and beautifulsoup from Gizmodo website

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm working on a side project trying to web scrape data from [this site](https://gizmodo.com/google-pixel-3-review-the-other-way-to-make-a-killer-p-1829749807).

However, when I grab the elements, tags, etc with the text I keep getting `noneType` object has no text (trying to print `comment.text` using BeautifulSoup functionality)

I've tried it on:

```
<p class="paragraphContainer__ParagraphContainer-sc-77igqf-0 gRtBxu">Well, congrats on it still working, but now you’re walking around with a beatup phone that will always look like a piece of shit. A $10 case would prevent that. An ugly beatup phone will just drive you to get another $1000 pocket super computer sooner. I bet that lens cost you more than $10. </p>
```

And on:

```
<div class="reply__content js_reply-content post-content blurable whitelisted-links"><p class="paragraphContainer__ParagraphContainer-sc-77igqf-0 gRtBxu">Well, congrats on it still working, but now you’re walking around with a beatup phone that will always look like a piece of shit. A $10 case would prevent that. An ugly beatup phone will just drive you to get another $1000 pocket super computer sooner. I bet that lens cost you more than $10. </p><p class="paragraphContainer__ParagraphContainer-sc-77igqf-0 gRtBxu">Go buy a case.</p></div>
```

And on:

```
//[@id="reply_1829766226"]/div[1]/p[1]/text()
```

I can do this for another site but not Gizmodo.  What am I missing?

Using this command:

```
text = soup.find("p", attrs="text")
```

or

```
text = soup.find_all("p", attrs="text")
```

With the above elements taking the place of `p` and the `attrs` as required. And searching for XPath when required as in the last element output.  My goal is to extract the entire text *"Well, congrats....."*

Comment: what you want to extract?

Comment: I edited to answer your question.

Comment: If at all _trying to print comment.text using beautifulsoup_ why tagging Selenium?

Comment: Because I'm not just trying to print.  I am trying to do something else.

Comment: What are you missing in the API results?

Comment: I did not use the API technique because I am trying to do something which requires the code to 1) open a web browser 2) loop through a list of valence words 3) loop through a list of sites 4) Select a given number of websites from each search and pull the comments from them. Using an API would make this static. I want it to be dynamic where the only thing being supplied by me is the initial search engine url, site name, the word, the product, the number of results to get from each search and then the code utilizes the search engine/selects the number of sites and pulls the comments.

Answer (score 1):

How about `API`

```
import requests


r = requests.get('https://gizmodo.com/ajax/comments/views/replies/1829749807?startIndex=0&maxReturned=5&maxChildren=4&approvedOnly=true&cache=true&experimental=true&sorting=top').json()

for item in r['data']['items']:
    for value in item['children']['items'][:]:
        for com in value['body'][:]:
            if "value" in com.keys():
                for sas in com['value'][0:]:
                    if 'value' in sas.keys():
                        print(sas['value'])
```

Output:

```
It’s turning into a longer-lasting problem, there aren’t many good phones available that have a headphone jack at this point. If that’s a dealbreaker, and the notch is a dealbreaker, you’re basically out of options. 
Yeah, I couldn’t care less about the notch really. But connecting peripherals      
 is important and I don’t own/plan on buying bluetooth headphones or carrying around an extra dongle to use wired
 headphones.
I use headphones
 infrequently enough that ensuring I have a battery powered device charged and ready all the time or carrying a dongle in my pocket
isn’t convenient
. But I use it just enough that when I want to connect my phone to the car aux jack (no bluetooth) or use a pair of wired headphones I don’t want to have to go digging for some other component.
USB-C headphones?
“But connecting peripherals is important and I don’t own/plan on buying bluetooth headphones or carrying around an extra dongle to use wired headphones.
”
Why can’t you just leave the dongle attached to the end of the headphones? Or      
 buy a pair of USB-C headphones?
Have you actually handled one in real life, or are you just trolling? I sincerely ask, because I did at my local BB store, and to my amazement the notch was not the first thing I noticed, it was the entirety of the phone that blew me away in it’s beauty. The display actually balances out the notch, that it’s actually not overwhelming or intrusive in any way.
I’m starring your comment
 just because you called their notch a “ballsack”, LOL
. It does dangle quite a lot, I’ll give you that.
I think if I were in the Android ecosystem, I’d buy this phone over anything from Samsung, LG, etc., but looking at the front face design makes me really appreciate the attention to detail
that Apple applies to the curves and proportions of
their phones. The front of my XS Max looks 100x better than this.
Alright guys, you heard the man. Shut it down. Google shouldn’t even try anymore.  
Apparently you can just think of the superior aesthetics of the phone every time you realize how awful the pictures are in comparison.
I mean, my Moto Z (not the “force” version) fell out of my backpack while riding a 
motorcycle the other day with nothing on it but a “TurboPower Pack”, then got run over by a car as I was pulling over to retrieve it.
Still 100% functional, with a new camera lens in the mail.
It’s possible to make a durable phone, just not when the whole damn thing is glass. At that point just use plastic, because it’s going to be covered by a plastic case
 anyway.
Well, congrats on it still working, but now you’re walking around with a beatup phone that will always look like a piece of shit. A $10 case would prevent that. An ugly beatup phone will just drive you to get another $1000 pocket super computer sooner. I bet that lens cost you more than $10.
Go buy a case.
What are you doing with your phone? iPhone 7, no case for over 2
 years. Phone has one little scuff in the top corner. I do have a pop socket, which I find reduced the droppability significantly.
No everyone has butter fingers.
LOL
, get a load of this guy.
P
robably because the specific panel they installed into the Pixel 3XL doesn’t have a foldable element(that the iPhone XS does).
The iPhone XS in truth has the screen fold
under
 the display, that’s how they were able to get the edge-to-edge at the bottom with 
no chin. It’s all an illusion.
Honestly, I personally hate phones with no "chin" whatsoever.  Edge to edge display certainly looks nice but with no buffer between the display and your hand it's too easy to accidentally interact with the edge of the screen.  I still accidentally hit enter a bunch of times with my palm while inputting text on my P2xl.
They did it specifically to troll people like you. Congratulations, you fell for it!
```

Comment: Please see my above comment on why this is not a solution to the problem.  While it certainly does work it is not usable to the problem I am trying to solve.  I decided to just remove Gizmodo from my list of sites to search atm.  Thanks for responding.

Comment: Also please upvote this question as it is a legitimate issue which has described in the upvote "This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear"  I can not get higher rep because people are not upvoting my questions but I see other similar questions get upvoted all the time.